# Creating a geopoint object from CSV (latitude and longitude columns) in Logstash

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a CSV with the columns `latitude` and `longitude` and I'm trying to create a `geopoint` object in Logstash 2.3.3 so that I can visualize these values in Kibana 4.5.1.

However when visualizing the data in Kibana, I see `location.lat` and `location.lon`, both of type `float` and not a `location` of type `geopoint`.

I'm new to ELK in general and this is driving me crazy. Especially because most of the information that I'm finding is outdated.

The `.conf` file that I'm using looks like this:

```
input {  
    file {
        path => "C:/file.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"    
    }
}

filter {  
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ["longitude","latitude"]
    }

    mutate { convert => {"latitude" => "float"} }
    mutate { convert => {"longitude" => "float"} }
    mutate { rename => {"latitude" => "[location][lat]"} }
    mutate { rename => {"longitude" => "[location][lon]"} }
    mutate { convert => { "[location]" => "float" } }
}

output {  
    elasticsearch {
        template => "...\elasticsearch-template.json"
        template_overwrite => true
        action => "index"
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "testindex1"
        workers => 1
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

The template file I'm specifying (`elasticsearch-template.json`) is the following:

```
{
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "_all" : {"enabled" : true, "omit_norms" : true},
      "dynamic_templates" : [ {
        "message_field" : {
          "match" : "message",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
            "fielddata" : { "format" : "disabled" }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "string_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
            "fielddata" : { "format" : "disabled" },
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "ignore_above" : 256}
            }
          }
        }
      } ],
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp": { "type": "date" },
        "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "geoip"  : {
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "ip": { "type": "ip" },
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" },
            "latitude" : { "type" : "float" },
            "longitude" : { "type" : "float" }
          }
        },
  "location" : { "type": "geo_point" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone could help me or give me some insight as to what I'm doing wrong, I would be very grateful. Also I'm sure this will help everyone who is on the same boat as me.

**I solved it and it is now working perfectly.** The template was looking for an index of the type `logstash-*` and I was using `testindex1`. Changing my index to `logstash-%{+dd.MM.YYYY}` fixed it.

Comment: In my opinion, you need to remove the last `mutate` which defeats the purpose of what you're trying to achieve. Also can you make sure that the `testindex1` mapping is faithfully containing the mapping you have in your `elasticsearch-template.json` file?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem was indeed on the `testindex1` mapping.

Comment: @val You should post that as the answer so that she can accept it. That's definitely the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the last `mutate` filter which defeats the purpose of what you're trying to achieve.

Also you need to make sure that the `testindex1` mapping is faithfully containing the mapping you have in your `elasticsearch-template.json` file